# disabling sha,sha1 or sha-1 using jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms in java.security

Tags: java, ssl

If I use the below in java.security (jdk 7 and even jdk 8) any update 
`jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, MD5withRSA,SHA,SHA1,SHA-1, DH keySize < 768`
and I have no certificates in the chain that are sha signed certificates, I get the below exception:

```
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unsupported SignatureAndHashAlgorithm in ServerKeyExchange message
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384]
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
```

I am trying to disable using `SHA`/`SHA1`/`SHA-1` as a message digest from the client side. Why do I get the above exception on `SHA384`.
If I remove the "SHAs" from the disabled algorithms in `java.security` all is fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: `Unsupported SignatureAndHashAlgorithm` should be indicative enough. Not sure if you have used `SHA-384`  over `SHA384` (you're not using the dash)..

Comment: Please elaborate. there is no mention in the java.security file of sha384 or sha-384 anywhere.